# Query to select a large range of columns without manually entering each column Google Sheets

Tags: join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am using the solution presented in this post:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101926/google-sheets-query-to-select-a-large-range-of-columns-without-manually-entering

But now I need to query data from a different spreadsheet. I know the `importrange` requires the use of 'Col' to specify the column. However, I don't know how to change this string:

```
=arrayformula(join(",", substitute(address(1, column(C:F), 4), "1", "")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",", "Col"&COLUMN(C:F)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: My script looks like this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A:W");"Select "&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ";"Col"&COLUMN(A:V))&" Where Col23 = 'X'")))`

But returns: "Error: Result too large. "

Comment: try: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A:W");"where Col23 = 'X'"); ROWS(A:A); 22)`

Comment: or like this: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A1:W5000");IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A5001:W10000")};"where Col23 = 'X'");999^99; 22))`

Comment: This script had the same problem: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A:W");"where Col23 = 'X'"); ROWS(A:A); 22)`
This script worked! `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A1:W5000");IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A5001:W10000")};"where Col23 = 'X'");999^99; 22))`
Does "999 ^ 99" mean infinity?

Comment: it doesn't mean "infinity", but it's rly big number. could be 88^88 or 200^64 or anything you wish like 987654321, etc. as far as it's not too small

Comment: This script extract data from a very dynamic spreadsheet. Sometimes they contain many lines, sometimes not.
When the second term `IMPORTRANGE("Sheet";"Test!A5001:W10000")` is empty, returns the error: "In ARRAY_CONSTRAIN, an array literal does not contain values ​​for one or more rows.".
Is there a way around this without having to change the script whenever the spreadsheet contains a few rows?

Comment: sure, wrap the `IMPORTRANGE("ID";"Test!A5001:W10000")` into `IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("ID";"Test!A5001:W10000"), SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(A:W)^0, 1, ))` every importrange needs to be wrapped into `IFERROR` also wrap your whole formula into  `ARRAYFORMULA`